# Can someone explain what is going on with line 3 // [a, b] = [b, a];

Tags: javascript, function

its simple but im a bit lost on what its doing besides swapping the values.

```
function shorter_reverse_longer(a,b){
    if (b.length > a.length)
        [a, b] = [b, a];
    return b + a.split('').reverse().join('') + b;
}
```

Comment: "besides swapping the values" It just swaps the values.

Comment: "its simple but im a bit lost on what its doing besides swapping the values." — Nothing. That's all that line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It creates an array with `[b, a]` and assigns each value to a, b by [destructuring an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Please refer to [this page](https://codeburst.io/using-destructing-for-objects-and-arrays-and-its-practical-examples-e3ebb13170e5?gi=9694e159f050).